# Access 2019 - Saved Import Overwrites Index and Field Selection Settings

Tags: ms-access, indexing, importerror

hope somebody can help me,

I have an Excel file, which I have set up an Saved Import (MySavedImport).
It runs from a specific .XLS file which never changes name or location, or column content.

When saving this file the first time, I deliberately ensured there was no indexes (on 2 ID fields), and that several fields were deselected to avoid importing them.

eg.

- UniqueID - no index, imported
- CustomerID - no index, NOT imported
- First Name - NOT imported
- Last Name - NOT imported

It runs fine during the first time it is saved and run.  There are no indexes saved, and only the selected fields I wanted are imported.  This is exactly what I want - every time.

If I try to run the Saved Import a few mins later to test, it errors out:

> --- Overwrite existing table or query 'Table_A'?     (yes,this is correct, I want to overwrite)

> --- Cannot delete a field that is part of an index or is needed by the system.   [OK]

> --- The specification failed to execute.  Try re-creating the specification.     [OK]

So - then I check Table_A

> --- it now has EVERY field imported, instead of just the ones that were selected in the Import.

> --- it also has TWO Indexes added, the UniqueID, and CustomerID - which were not originally saved in the Import

.

?????

I'm confused, why is the saved import not retaining my specifications in the import process?
Better, how can I stop this and make it work as it should?

Any assistance on this is greatly appreciated.    Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  However, the proposed answer did not match the circumstances, but did help me thinking more about the process.

Comment: For those playing at home, I did come up with a workaround (although not answer as to 'why' required) --- I just have to include the CustomerID field regardless of whether I want it or not, then deal with it once imported.  (I left it as Duplicates OK, because of... reasons.)   To Summarise:  If there is a field in your import that Access thinks is/should be Indexed - IMPORT IT ALSO.   Cheers.